# Where to place Zend_Forms, Controller? Model? Somewhere else?

Tags: zend-framework, forms, model, zend-form

Where is it best to put the code for building my Zend_Forms?

I used to put this logic inside my Controllers, but moved away from that after I needed to use the same form in different places. It meant I had to duplicate the creation of forms in different controllers.

So I moved the form creation code into my Models. Does this seem right, it works for me. Or is there something I am missing, and they should in fact go somewhere else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually put my form building code in separate files, one file per form.
Additionally I configure the [Resource Autoloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html) so that I can load my forms in my controllers.

application/forms/Login.php

```
<?php
class Form_Login extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->addElement('text', 'username', array(
            'filters'    => array('StringTrim', 'StringToLower'),
            'required'   => true,
            'label'      => 'Username:',
        ));

        $this->addElement('password', 'password', array(
            'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
            'required'   => true,
            'label'      => 'Password:',
        ));

        $this->addElement('submit', 'login', array(
            'ignore'   => true,
            'label'    => 'Submit',
        ));
    }
}
```

In my controllers:

```
$loginForm = new Form_Login();
```

Comment: +1 I'd add also `$model->getForm();` where in model `public function getForm() {return new Form_Login;}`, so the form is always sticky to the model.

Comment: "Additionally I configure the Resource Autoloader so that I can load my forms in my controllers". Any chance you could elaborate on this?

Comment: voidstate: Maybe this answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264812/autoloading-in-zend-framework/6265759#6265759