# Autoloading in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, autoload, zend-autoloader

how to autoload a class in custom directory on module path. My application's structure is like below

```
application
|_ modules
   |_admin
     |_api
     | |_Core.php
     |_elements
       |_Dialog.php
```

i have two custom directory, 'api' and 'elements', when i instantiated an object of that two class i have received error message: 'Fatal error class Admin_Api_Core is not found'. I try with registerNamespace but it not work at all

```
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()->registerNamespace('Admin_');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure autoloading inside your Module_Bootstrap (almost same approach as in Benjamin Cremer's answer but module based).
To do it - create file Bootstrap.php in /modules/admin folder with the following content:

```
class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{

    protected function _initAutoload()
    {
        $resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
            'basePath'      => realpath(dirname(__FILE__)),
            'namespace'     => 'Admin',
            'resourceTypes' => array(
                'api' => array(
                    'path'      => 'api/',
                    'namespace' => 'Api'
                )
            )
        ));

        $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => 'Admin',
            'basePath'  => dirname(__FILE__),
            'resourceloader' => $resourceLoader
        ));
        return $autoloader;
    }

}
```

After that you'll be able to instantiate class Admin_Api_Core etc. (you should specify all resoursTypes). If you have many modules, you can create such bootstraps for all of them.

Comment: Excellent, this work! Thank you very much ischenkodv <- your name is hard to spell :-d

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at ZFs [Resource Autoloaders](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html).

Add the following to your Bootstrap.php

```
protected function _resourceLoader()
{
    $resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
        'basePath'      => 'APPLICATION_PATH',
        'namespace'     => '',
        'resourceTypes' => array(
            'acl' => array(
                'path'      => 'api/',
                'namespace' => 'Acl',
            ),
            'form' => array(
                'path'      => 'elements/',
                'namespace' => 'Element',
            ),
        ),
    ));
}
```

Api_Core loads `APPLICATION_PATH . '/api/Core.php`
Element_Core loads `APPLICATION_PATH . '/elements/Core.php`
Admin_Api_Core loads `APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/admin/api/Core.php`
Admin_Element_Core loads `APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/admin/elements/Core.php`

Comment: not work at all, the default basepath is not an admin module, but another module, if i push to set the default to admin yes it works, but if i set to another one it not work